# how do you append to a list in a pandas cell inside a copy of a dataframe without modifying the original?

Tags: python, pandas, append

I'm pretty much confused by the notions of views in pandas and the way pandas dataframe references its content when copied. I'm sure experts here can give me some straight answers. I'm very thick when it comes to this or numpy philosophy and I guess those two are related.

Here is a typical example :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from random import randint
print "done importing modules"

def aRandomRow() :
    out={}
    out['aDate'] = datetime.datetime(randint(2010,2018),randint(1,12),randint(1,28))
    out['aScalar']=randint(1,1000)
    out['anArray']=[randint(1,1000),randint(1,1000),randint(1,1000)]
    out['anArDate']=[datetime.datetime(randint(2010,2018),randint(1,12),randint(1,28)),datetime.datetime(randint(2010,2018),randint(1,12),randint(1,28)),datetime.datetime(randint(2010,2018),randint(1,12),randint(1,28))]
    return out

# Now the dataframes for the examples
df=pd.DataFrame([aRandomRow(),aRandomRow(),aRandomRow()])
df1=df.copy()
df2=df.copy(deep=True)

#I get something like this :

aDate   aScalar anArDate    anArray
0   2016-07-28  5   [2015-02-06 00:00:00, 2015-12-14 00:00:00, 201...   [121, 67, 277]
1   2014-05-04  39  [2015-11-03 00:00:00, 2014-04-23 00:00:00, 201...   [939, 105, 714]
2   2010-12-01  157 [2015-07-05 00:00:00, 2012-05-06 00:00:00, 201...   [43, 79, 230]

#Now I modify the copies and check the result on the original 
df1.loc[0,'aDate'] = 1001
df2.loc[0,'aDate'] = 1002
# df1 and df2 get modified but not df. As intuitively intended.
df1.loc[0,'anArray'].append(1001)
df2.loc[0,'anArray'].append(1002)

# the list inside the cell index 0  of df.anArray gets appended with 1001 and 1002 

# that is what bugs/puzzle me ! 
    aDate   aString anArDate    anArray
0   2016-07-28  5   [2015-02-06 00:00:00, 2015-12-14 00:00:00, 201...   [121, 67, 277, 1001, 1001, 1002]
1   2014-05-04  39  [2015-11-03 00:00:00, 2014-04-23 00:00:00, 201...   [939, 105, 714]
2   2010-12-01  157 [2015-07-05 00:00:00, 2012-05-06 00:00:00, 201...   [43, 79, 230]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pd.DataFrame.copy` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) states

> Note that when deep=True data is copied, actual python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object. This is in contrast to copy.deepcopy in the Standard Library, which recursively copies object.

You can achieve a true copy using the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

```
import copy
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2]]})
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
for c in df1:
    df1[c] = [copy.deepcopy(e) for e in df1[c]]
```

Comment: can't upvote , so I'm mentioning for whoever reads it , your solution works ! (and thank you) , I can now define a true copy function.